# Pandas hierarchical indexing - not working for dataframe?

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I'm having trouble addressing values in a DataFrame, but I don't seem to have any problems with the Series object.

```
>>> df=DataFrame([0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5], index=[['a','a','b','b','b'],[1,2,1,2,3]])
>>> series=Series([0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5], index=[['a','a','b','b','b'],[1,2,1,2,3]])
>>> series['a']
1    0.5
2    1.5
dtype: float64
>>> df['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2003, in __getitem__
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 667, in _get_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1655, in get
_, block = self._find_block(item)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1935, in _find_block
self._check_have(item)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1942, in _check_have
raise KeyError('no item named %s' % com.pprint_thing(item))
KeyError: u'no item named a'
```

I'm definitely misunderstanding something, if someone could help me out it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: `df['a']` selecting a column, you can use `df.ix['a']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to select a column, and there is indeed no column named 'a'. Try `df.loc['a']` instead.

I recommend to look at the basic indexing docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics
In summary:

- `series[label]` selects element in series at index `label`
- `dataframe[label]` selects column with name `label`

Comment: thanks for redirecting to `df.loc`  confusing since numpy[idx] refers to rows and pandas[idx] refers to columns .... R semantics invading python :-O

Comment: Thanks for the concise and clear explanation of the differences here